# jQuery Cross Site Fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I feel like this is easy but I am missing something...

Using jQuery, I am trying to fetch a remote page (on a different server), capture the HTML contents, and inject that content into a hidden DIV.  However, using either $.ajax or $.get results in a cross-site scripting error in FireFox.

Any suggestions?  Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.remote-url.com",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#put_here').empty().append(data);
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Chad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that - the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents it for security reasons (as you've found).

You need to [run a proxy script](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy) on your own server that your JavaScript uses to fetch the content from the remote server on its behalf.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use already-existing APIs like YQL or Pipes to access the data you're after... and then return results using JSONP (cross-domain operable).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX disallows cross-domain fetching.  You must have your server fetch from whatever server you want to get information from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go cross site, you can't pull in an entire page. There is a way to get data from cross domain sites using JSONP. What you do, is make the js call the data you get back as a function which will evaluate json data. But wont work if you are trying to fetch an entire page, however.