# JQuery Load Page Content into Div

Tags: jquery, html, load

I found lots of questions/answers regarding how to load page content into a div; however, I can't get mine to load.  I am running the jquery inside document.ready.  Running an alert by itself works fine, but the code below does not.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
//First I tried this:
$("#divTestPreview").load("~/Testing/TestCreation/AddTestItems.aspx");
//and then I tried this:
$.get('~/Testing/TestCreation/AddTestItems.aspx', function (data) {
            $('#divTestPreview').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
});

<div id="divTestPreview" runat="server" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050996/jquery-cross-site-fetch

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry, my test with google, was not a good one since I am trying to load a page within my own site.  Edited code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your div has runat="server" tag which makes it a server side control. To access it in client side you need to use ClientID to access the div.
Like this

```
$("#<% divTestPreview.ClientID %>").load();
```

Comment: it should be "#<%divTestPreview.ClientID %>"

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work for me: `$("#" + "ctl00_mainContent_divTestPreview").load("http://www.google.com");` (rendered code)

Comment: it because you you are trying to load some page which is not in your domain(i.e., google.com). For doing cross domain requests refer to the links provided by kleinohad above

Comment: try $("#<% divTestPreview.ClientID %>").load("/Testing/TestCreation/AddTestItems.aspx");

Comment: That got me further, but I am getting errors on a dynamically generated page.  I think I am going to load the content a different way.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the runat="server" in your div as I think your ASP.NET interpreter might be fiddling with the HTML before it reaches the client.

Thanks!

Comment: Depends. If you have turned ClientIDMode to static, it won't mess with the id. But like I said, that depends on the mode, and of course that it's run on .NET4. Just as a side note :)

Comment: @Gauthic is correct asp.net will generate an id when the page is rendered. if you need to keep the runat="server" then use $("#" + <%=divTestPreview.ClientID%> +").load(...

Comment: The rendered code looks like this:
`$.get('http://www.google.com', function (data) {
                $("#" + "ctl00_mainContent_divTestPreview").html(data);
                alert('Load was performed.');
            });`

Answer (score 1):

you can use load and get to load only pages inside your domain other wise you will get cross domain error there is a solution for it you need to create some sort of proxy read this: [WebBrowser Control: Disable Cross Site XSS Filtering or another way to process JS in full on HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477432/webbrowser-control-disable-cross-site-xss-filtering-or-another-way-to-process-js/6483485#6483485) or you can try this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: load & get can load pages from just about anywhere.. get & load are usually used to load pages from the same domain... however this does not mean that they can't be used to load contents from a different site.

Comment: this exactly means that you can't load data from other domain unless doing so in the server side (as a proxy) and use the same domain (server) on javascript

Comment: Thanks! I am actually trying to access a local page: `$("#" + "ctl00_mainContent_divTestPreview").load("~/Testing/TestCreation/AddTestItems.aspx");` (rendered code)

Answer (score 0):

That is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, you are making
cross domain AJAX, and it's no possible in current versions browsers,
you have to do it in the server side, for example in PHP with 
fopen() o file_get_contents(), if you need to make it on client side,
there are many options like flensed FLXHR or CORS for modern browsers.